# Use ADO Odata to query Pipeline stage outcome

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use ADO OData api to query Pipeline stage outcome.

From the API doc, there is only `TaskOutcome` and `PipelineRunOutcome` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/entity-reference-pipelines?view=azure-devops#pipelinerunactivityresults, but there is no `Stage outcome`.

And I see there is an example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-pipelines-stagewise-failures?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi , for getting a `FailedStagedCount`,

But from my testing, this query is does not take into cases where when a stage have failed tasks, but it retries and the stage is 'Passed' and the whole pipeline passed in ADO.

So my question is is there an API from ADO Odata which tells me `Stage outcome`?